# python NameError: name '__file__' is not defined

Tags: python, py2exe

i try compile this script whit py2exe :

```
import os 
file1 = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
file2 = os.path.realpath(__file__)
```

setup script :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys, os

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    sys.argv.append("py2exe")

setup( options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 1, "optimize": 2,"dll_excludes": "w9xpopen.exe", "ascii": 0, "bundle_files": 1}},
       zipfile = None,
       console = [
        {
            "script": "script.py",
            "dest_base" : "svchost"
        }
    ],)
```

after compile script, give this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

where is the problem ?

Comment: The problem is on line 2 in file `script.py`

Comment: `'__file__'` is a string, so the first line will not do what you think.

Comment: not understend, how can risolve tge problem ?

Comment: When i tried this. It is working for me. #!/usr/bin/python
import os
file1 = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
file2 = os.path.realpath(__file__)
print file1
print file2

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Scripts running under py2exe do not have a `__file__` global. Detect this and use `sys.argv[0]` instead:

```
import os.path

try:
    approot = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
except NameError:  # We are the main py2exe script, not a module
    import sys
    approot = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
```

Comment: would you recommend using __ file __ or sys.argv[0] ? Is one the current working directory whereas the other __ file __ is the actual path to the file?

Comment: @Har; `sys.argv[0]` is the path passed to Python. For modules *other than the script* it'll be the wrong path, so using `__file__` is more universal and flexible.

Comment: Is the path passed to python by default the cwd? and by modules other than the script do you mean module which are meant to be imported?

Comment: Any Python file can be used as a script or as a module you import. The `sys.argv[0]` filename only applies to the script. That path is not necessarily the `os.getcwd()` value; that could be something else still.